# I get an error message when I use Xamarin Essentials SecureStorage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I want to use SecureStorage on iOS and Android mobile phones and tablets but I get this error message on iOS. I have not yet tested SecureStorage on Android.

[Xamarin Essentials SecureStorage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?tabs=android)

What is wrong? What does the error mean?

[Error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJwP2.png)

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as text ([using code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format »» code/errors/data as an image » nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you did not add the Keychain entitlement that is mentioned to be added to `Entitlement.plist`

If you check the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?tabs=ios#get-started) it says:

> When developing on the iOS simulator, enable the Keychain entitlement and add a keychain access group for the application's bundle identifier.
>
> Open the Entitlements.plist in the iOS project and find the Keychain entitlement and enable it. This will automatically add the application's identifier as a group.
>
> In the project properties, under iOS Bundle Signing set the Custom Entitlements to Entitlements.plist.

Also under [Platform Specifics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?tabs=ios#platform-implementation-specifics) it says:

> KeyChain is used to store values securely on iOS devices. The SecRecord used to store the value has a Service value set to [YOUR-APP-BUNDLE-ID].xamarinessentials.
>
> In some cases, KeyChain data is synchronized with iCloud, and uninstalling the application may not remove the secure values from iCloud and other devices of the user.

I hope this helps,

Goodluck

Revert in case of queries.

Comment: Please, look my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67673288/could-not-find-any-available-provisioning-profiles

Comment: Note that Entitlements are needed for the simulator but not for actual device. I could not find another way except creating two different entitlements lists and switching between them when working on device or simulator.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a simulator, check the documentation here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/questions/no-codesigning-keys

> You can workaround the issue by removing the
>  flag from the debug builds in the .csproj file.

Search CodesignEntitlements in your project and delete that line. then, clean and restart your simulator

Another possible problem is that your provisioning profile is not yet set up
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/