# Could not find any available provisioning profiles

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I don’t understand what the problem is, I can’t find a solution on the net. What is the problem? I use a simulator in conjunction with a Mac computer. I am getting the following error:

> Could not find any available provisioning profiles for DriverHelper v
> 2.0.iOS on iOS.

Do I have to do something in the developer account?

[image]

Comment: Since you're using simulator did you try using the wildcard provisioning?

Comment: @FreakyAli Are you mean "App ID Configuration" ?

Comment: The screenshot is in a language that I don't understand, what I am saying is to run the app on simulator you can use wildcard provisioning https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/automatic-provisioning?tabs=macos